# file write permission denied in firebreath npplugin

Tags: c++, c, linux, firebreath

Source code is already tested in Fedora 15,16 and Ubuntu 10, 11, 12 and no problem.

But in Fedora 17, file write function didn't work.

1)

```
int fd;
if ( 0 < ( fd = open("/home/test/temp/opentest.html", O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0777))) {
    write(fd, "test", strlen("test"));
    close(fd);
    return "Success";
} else {
    return "Error";
}
```

Return Value : Error

2)

```
FILE *pFile;
pFile = fopen("/home/test/temp/opentest.html", "w+");
if (pFile == NULL) {
    return "Pointer is NULL";
} else {
    fputs("fopen test", pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
    return "Success";
}
```

Return Value : "Pointer is NULL"

I guess directory's permission makes error and set 777 permission.
But nothing is changed.

Same code worked in normal C program.

Why didn't it worked in firebreath npPlugin?

Is there any difference about permission?

Comment: Is there any other purpose of mktemp function without creating temp file? I should create html file and set file name what I want.

Comment: Oops, i actually meant to link [`mkstemp(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkstemp). If it's just a temporary file, the naming shouldn't matter, so the purpose would be to not hard-code the temp dir in case a distribution differs from what you expect.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But it isn't just a temporary file and name is passed as parameter from javascript. It must not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the directory doesn't exist, or you don't have permission to write to it.

Does this command work?
`echo 123 > /home/test/temp/opentest.html`

Comment: In support of this idea, be aware that a FireBreath plugin has exactly the same permissions as the browser that hosts it; Chrome keeps threatening to sandbox NPAPI plugins more, but as far as I know they are not doing so on linux at this time, and no other browsers do that as far as I am aware.

Comment: @taxilian I tested this plugin in firefox and I ran firefox with root account but it still didn't work. I exeperienced same problem in Windows 7 and solved with UAC elevation. Is there any solution to elevate permission of firefox or npplugin for writing file?

Comment: well, you could launch a seperate process using a variant of sudo, but generally the correct solution on *nix is to simply not write to places where you don't have permissions. The point of @ugoren's answer (which you haven't addressed either way) is that you're probably trying to write somewhere that the user doesn't have access to.

Comment: That directory is created for this plugin. So I want to set permission  for read/write and write file in there. I use chmod 777 command to allow all permission. Is there anything else I should do?